# javascript xampp client connection

Tags: javascript, xampp, strophe

I try to develop chat application using xampp and jsxc.

when i try to connect with xampp using this http://localhost:5280/http-bind/ url i get this error.

> POST http://54.69.166.107:5280/http-bind/
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSEDjsxc.dep.js:4458 sendFunc

I am stuck at this position. This is my function which i written for connection.

```
 $(function() {
        jsxc.init({
            loginForm: {
                form: '#form',
                jid: '#username',
                pass: '#password'
            },
            logoutElement: $('#logout'),
            rosterAppend: 'body',
            root: '/jsxc.example/',
            turnCredentialsPath: 'ajax/getturncredentials.json',
            loadSettings: function(username, password) {
                return {
                    xmpp: {
                        url: 'http://localhost:5280/http-bind/',
                        domain: 'localhost',
                        resource: 'example',
                        onlogin: true
                    }
                };
            }
        });
    });
```

Please suggest me some good ideas for connection. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I set proxy in httpd.conf (apache) file in xampp.    

ProxyPass /http-bind/ http://localhost:5280/http-bind/    

ProxyPassReverse /http-bind/ http://localhost:5280/http-bind/